# Cordova : white screen on BlackBerry10 and deviceready not firing

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I'm building a multiplatform app with cordova 5.1.1, it works great on iOS and Android, but I'm getting a bit frustrated because the screen is white on blackberry 10.

By using the remote webinspector i can see these logs in console :

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:999
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady cordova.js:992
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:999
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady cordova.js:992
```

I saw some post talking about including "webworks.js" but they're kinda old and I don't think if they still apply nowadays.

Could you guys help me with this issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Cordova's [official documentation for building for BlackBerry 10](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_blackberry10_index.md.html) indicates that you should install the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK to build apps for BB10. This has also been my own experience. Building for Android requires the Android SDK installed -- it only makes sense that the same would be true for BlackBerry 10.

You can download the SDK here:
http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/

If you're not developing any native extensions, you can skip the part about needing the native SDK.

What I'm not sure about is if you have to explicitly include webworks.js. Perhaps it isn't needed or is injected to the WebView. It's one line of HTML though...add it and see what happens.

Good luck!